# Equivalence between function(x) and purrr::map

Tags: r

I have this list:

```
list(structure(list(a = 1:10, b = 2:11, c = 3:12), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
a = 1:10, b = 2:11, c = 3:12), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(a = 1:10, b = 2:11, 
c = 3:12), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame"))
```

And this function:

```
fun1<-function(x){
  funs<-c(s=sum,m=mean)
  lapply(funs,function(f)f(x,na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

With `lapply` the result is ok. See:

```
list%>%
  lapply(function(x){
    lapply(x,fun1)
  })
```

But, `purrr::map` doesn't work:

```
list%>%
  map(.)%>%
  map(.,fun1)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You cant use the `.` inside of `map` without a `~`  to define a lambda function, `li %>% map(~ map(., fun1))` works tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for the map part is wrong. You need the same code structure as you are using with lapply. First let's get rid of the pipes so the code looks more alike:

Also don't give objects the same name as R functions.

```
library(purrr)

lapply_outcome <- lapply(my_list, function(x) {lapply(x, fun1)})

map_outcome <- map(my_list, function(x) {map(x, fun1)})

identical(lapply_outcome, map_outcome)

[1] TRUE
```

With pipes:

```
my_list %>%
  lapply(function(x) lapply(x,fun1))

my_list %>% 
  map(., function(x) map(x, fun1))
```

or with a formula call inside map, but personally I find this less readable:

```
my_list %>% 
  map(~ map(., fun1))
```